# use multi-threading to generate a matrix in java to utilize all CPU cores of a supercomputer

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix

i am working on a problem which deals with large amount of data and computation also for all that purpose we have a supercomputer with processing power of 270 T FLOPS so our data is basically in matrix form so we decided to divide the generation of matrix into several parts by using threads so problem is there only that how can we implement such thing in our function we are just using arguments to divide task but run function of thread is not taking arguments

```
static int start=0,end;
int row=10000;
int col =10000,count=0,m=2203,n=401;
double p=Math.PI,t=Math.sqrt(3),pi=(p/(col+1));
double mul,a,b,c,d,e,f,xx,yy;
int[][] matrix = new int [row][col];


private void sin1()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method 
    for (int i =start; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <col; j++) 
        {
            xx=((i+1)*pi);
            yy=((j+1)*pi);
            a=Math.cos(((2*m)-n)*((2*(xx))/3));
            b=Math.sin(((2*(n*(yy)))/t));
            c=Math.cos(((((2*n)-m)*(2*(xx)))/3));
            d=Math.sin(((2*m)*(yy)/t));
            e=Math.cos((((m+n)*(2*(xx)))/3));
            f=Math.sin((((m-n)*(2*(yy)))/t));

               mul=(a*b)-(c*d)+(e*f);

            if(mul<0)
            {
                matrix[i][j]=0;
            }
            else
            {
                matrix[i][j]=1;
            }
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

we at first testing it for 10 million values

Comment: This is hard. Look for a good library.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen can you suggest something better

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the function above is just for testing a another program after this it is getting more complicated

Comment: No.  But at your current skill level multi-thread programming may be too complicated to do to get any advantage as there is a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The code makes it clear to me that you lack any form of Java programming knowledge. This is a bad thing if you want to write code for a super computer. Java luckily has a good set of tools to solve all kinds of problems, but you need to know which tools to use for which situation.

In your case you can i.E. use parallel streams to spread the generation across cores like this:

```
static final int start = 0;
static int end;
static final int row = 10000;
static final int col = 10000, count = 0, m = 2203, n = 401;
static final double t = Math.sqrt(3);
static final double pi = (Math.PI / (col + 1));

final int[][] matrix = new int[row][col];

public int generateMatrixEntry(final int i, final int j) {
  final double xx = ((i + 1) * pi);
  final double yy = ((j + 1) * pi);
  final double a = Math.cos(((2 * m) - n) * ((2 * (xx)) / 3));
  final double b = Math.sin(((2 * (n * (yy))) / t));
  final double c = Math.cos(((((2 * n) - m) * (2 * (xx))) / 3));
  final double d = Math.sin(((2 * m) * (yy) / t));
  final double e = Math.cos((((m + n) * (2 * (xx))) / 3));
  final double f = Math.sin((((m - n) * (2 * (yy))) / t));

  final double mul = (a * b) - (c * d) + (e * f);
  return (mul < 0) ? 0 : 1;
}

private void sin1() {
  IntStream.range(start, row).parallel().forEach((i) -> {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      matrix[i][j] = generateMatrixEntry(i, j);
    }
  });
}
```

This is however just one possible solution that might or might not fit your hardware. You absolutely need someone with deeper Java knowledge to select the right tools from the set for you if the above does not solve your issues.

Comment: thanks for your help and one problem is more that super computer don't support multi-threading as it is as it consider it as a one program so  only one core get allocated to me basically we are doing it for a physics analysis only so is there any way that the job scheduler of that PC take it as different processes and our task get done faster

Comment: The above code, specifically `parallel()`, will use as many cores as the process is allowed to use. If in your special setup you need to use a different mechanic - those jobs you mentioned - then you need an API for those jobs and a specific program that uses that API. If that is the case then no one here on SO can help you with that, as no one knows how the internals of your system are handled.

Comment: I want to study this function in detail can you please provide me some link or documentation

Comment: You should start here to understand the concept of streams: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

Parallel streams are simply streams that run in parallel.